# Are all data types a specific type of an class?

Tags: class, dart, object, oop, types

if all data types of dart language is class so
why when it's not assigned like that
int y = int(); or int(45);
String x = String(); or String ('Ahmed');
it's confused me

Comment: Some core, built-in types have special syntax ("literals") that allow the Dart compiler to construct the appropriate objects at compilation time without needing to explicitly call those constructors explicitly (e.g. `int y = 45; String x = 'Ahmed';`).  Furthermore, when you do `int(45)` or `String('Ahmed')`, you're already using `int` and `String` literals as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

All Dart values are objects.

All non-function values are instances of a specific class and implements a number of interfaces.

(Function values can technically be seen as each having their own class, but in practice those classes don't really exist. Function values still implement the class interfaces `Function` and `Object`.)

Dart classes can have different constructors. There is no rule that a Dart class must have an unnamed constructor taking zero or one arguments.

If you write `int y = int();`, you get an error because the `int` class does not have an unnamed zero-argument constructor.
The same way `int(45)` is invalid because the `int` class doesn't have an unnamed one-argument constructor.

(The only constructor the `int` class has is `int.fromEnvironment`, which is an `external const factory` constructor. You can read that as it being "magic".)

Similarly, the `String` class does not have an unnamed constructor taking zero or one arguments, so you can't write `String()` or `String('Ahmed')`. Not because it's invalid syntax, it's just trying to call a constructor which does't exist.

The `String` class has `String.fromCharCode`/`String.fromCharCodes` as constructors that you can use.

You seem to be assuming that because something, `X`, is a class, you can write `X()` or `X(someXValue)`. That's just not true in Dart. You have to look at each class to see which constructors it actually has.